# Use an IIFE approach and pass a variable from one file to another

Tags: javascript, d3.js

One of [my previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194923/showing-two-d3-js-charts-on-the-same-page) questions was how to organize the code between multiple .js files.
Now I have a problem.

I have a map in d3.js divided by countries. When the user double-clicks on a country, I would like to pass a variable to another js file.

This is my html file, **index.hbs**:

```
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
        <script src='https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

        <link href='/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>

        <script> 
            var viewData = {};  
            viewData.nuts0 = JSON.parse('{{json nuts0}}'.replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&lt;/, ''));
            viewData.CONFIG = JSON.parse('{{json CONFIG}}'.replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&lt;/, '')); 
        </script>

        <script src='/script/map.js' rel='script'/><{{!}}/script>
        <script src='/script/other.js' rel='script'/><{{!}}/script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**map.js**:

```
var NAME=(function map() {

    var my = {};

    var CONFIG = viewData.CONFIG;
    var nuts0 = viewData.nuts0;

    // paths
    var countries;

    // width and height of svg map container
    var width = CONFIG.bubbleMap.width;
    var height = CONFIG.bubbleMap.height;

    // to check if user clicks or double click
    var dblclick_timer = false;

    // create Hammer projection
    var projectionCurrent = d3.geoHammer() 
        .scale(1) 
        .translate([width/2, height/2]); 

    var projectionBase = d3.geoHammer()
        .scale(1) 
        .translate([width/2, height/2]);

    // creates a new geographic path generator with the default settings. If projection is specified, sets the current projection
    var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projectionCurrent);

    // creates the svg element that contains the map
    var map = d3.select('#map');

    var mapSvg = map.append('svg')
        .attr('id', 'map-svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

    var mapSvgGCountry = mapSvg.append('g').attr('id', 'nuts0');

    countries = topojson.feature(nuts0, nuts0.objects.nuts0);
    projectionCurrent.fitSize([width, height], countries);

    var mapSvgGCountryPath = mapSvgGCountry.selectAll('path')
        .data(countries.features)
        .enter()
        .append('path');

    mapSvgGCountryPath.attr('class', 'country')
        .attr('fill', 'tomato')
        .style('stroke', 'white')
        .style('stroke-width', 1) 
        .attr('d', path)
        .attr('id', function(c) {
            return 'country' + c.properties.nuts_id;
        })
        .on('click', clickOrDoubleCountry);

    function clickOrDoubleCountry(d, i) {
        if(dblclick_timer) { // double click
            clearTimeout(dblclick_timer);
            dblclick_timer = false;
            my.countryDoubleClicked = d.country; // <-- variable to pass
        }
        else { // single click
            dblclick_timer = setTimeout(function() {
                dblclick_timer = false;
            }, 250)
        } 
    } 

    return my;

}());
```

**other.js**:

```
(function other(NAME) {
    console.log('my:', NAME.my); // undefined
    console.log('my:', NAME.countryDoubleClicked); // undefined
})(NAME);
```

I would like to be able to read the my object created in `map.js` in the `other.js` file and then be able to access the `my.countryDoubleClicked` variable from `other.js`.

This code doesn't work, I get `TypeError: NAME.my is undefined`.

Comment: `function new` Probably best to call a function something *other* than a reserved keyword..?

Comment: The first line can't work because you're returning `my`, not an object with a property named `my`.   I can't see the issue with the second line yet (if there is one).   It certainly will be undefined until such time as the `clickOrDoubleCountry` event handler is invoked.

Comment: @Alnitak: Very good point

Comment: @Alnitak I don't know if I understand what you mean but of course, obviously the variable must be passed when the event occurs

Comment: @Alnitak Even if I add `my.a = 'a';` immediately under `var my = {};` (in `map.js`), I get anyway **TypeError: NAME.my is undefined**...

Comment: @KatherineMaurus please try to create a _small, self contained example_ with the bare minimum of code relating to the passing of that object that doesn't have all of the D3 requirements

Comment: I am the author of the answer in that question that suggests the use of IIFEs. However, I suggested that for a completely different code, not this one you have right now: the first "I" in "IIFE" means *immediately*. Therefore, the whole question here makes little sense: the variable only exists after the user clicks on the country, but an IIFE is executed immediately. What can be done here is *calling* a given function only after the user clicks on a country, which is a different matter.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks, I under stand what you mean but can you post an example code? Right now, I can't imagine how can I solve..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things going on:

### Revealing Variables

First you're not revealing the `my` variable to show up as `NAME.my` in **map.js**:

```
var NAME = (function map() {
    var my = {};
    //...
    return my;
}());
```

This sets `NAME` to `my`, instead of setting `NAME.my` to `my`. If you do want to do this, you can do something like this:

```
var NAME = (function map() {
    var my = {};
    //...
    return {
      my: my
    };
}());
```

You can read more about this technique, called the "Revealing Module Pattern", from articles like this one: http://jargon.js.org/_glossary/REVEALING_MODULE_PATTERN.md

### Using functions to run code later

Second, as others have mentioned and as you've realized, since the code in `other.js` runs immediately, it'll run that code before the user has any chance to click on a country. Instead, you want code that can run on demand, (in this case when the user double clicks on something). In JavaScript, this is traditionally done by assigning or passing a function. For simplicity, we can assign something to `my.doubleClickHandler` and then invoke that function in `clickOrDoubleCountry`. For this I've made the country an argument passed to the handler, in addition to assigning it to `NAME.my.countryDoubleClicked`, but you'll probably only need to use one of them.

```
function clickOrDoubleCountry(d, i) {
    if(dblclick_timer) { // double click
        clearTimeout(dblclick_timer);
        dblclick_timer = false;
        my.countryDoubleClicked = d.country; // <-- variable to pass
        if (my.doubleClickHandler) {
            my.doubleClickHandler(d.country);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then in `other.js`, you'd assign the function you want to run to `NAME.my.doubleClickHandler`:

```
(function other(NAME) {
    NAME.my.doubleClickHandler = function (country) {
        // now this code runs whenever the user double clicks on something
        console.log('exposed variable', NAME.my.countryDoubleClicked); // should be the country
        console.log('argument', country); // should be the same country
    });
})(NAME);
```

So in addition to the modified **other.js** above, this is complete modified **map.js**:

```
var NAME=(function map() {

    var my = {};

    var CONFIG = viewData.CONFIG;
    var nuts0 = viewData.nuts0;

    // paths
    var countries;

    // width and height of svg map container
    var width = CONFIG.bubbleMap.width;
    var height = CONFIG.bubbleMap.height;

    // to check if user clicks or double click
    var dblclick_timer = false;

    // create Hammer projection
    var projectionCurrent = d3.geoHammer() 
        .scale(1) 
        .translate([width/2, height/2]); 

    var projectionBase = d3.geoHammer()
        .scale(1) 
        .translate([width/2, height/2]);

    // creates a new geographic path generator with the default settings. If projection is specified, sets the current projection
    var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projectionCurrent);

    // creates the svg element that contains the map
    var map = d3.select('#map');

    var mapSvg = map.append('svg')
        .attr('id', 'map-svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

    var mapSvgGCountry = mapSvg.append('g').attr('id', 'nuts0');

    countries = topojson.feature(nuts0, nuts0.objects.nuts0);
    projectionCurrent.fitSize([width, height], countries);

    var mapSvgGCountryPath = mapSvgGCountry.selectAll('path')
        .data(countries.features)
        .enter()
        .append('path');

    mapSvgGCountryPath.attr('class', 'country')
        .attr('fill', 'tomato')
        .style('stroke', 'white')
        .style('stroke-width', 1) 
        .attr('d', path)
        .attr('id', function(c) {
            return 'country' + c.properties.nuts_id;
        })
        .on('click', clickOrDoubleCountry);

    function clickOrDoubleCountry(d, i) {
        if(dblclick_timer) { // double click
            clearTimeout(dblclick_timer);
            dblclick_timer = false;
            my.countryDoubleClicked = d.country; // <-- variable to pass
            if (my.doubleClickHandler) {
                my.doubleClickHandler(d.country);
            }
        }
        else { // single click
            dblclick_timer = setTimeout(function() {
                dblclick_timer = false;
            }, 250)
        } 
    } 

    return {
        my: my
    };

}());
```

If you don't want to use `NAME.my` for everything and want methods and variables accessible directly from `NAME` (e.g. `NAME.countryDoubleClicked` instead of `NAME.my.countryDoubleClicked`), you can use the original return statement `return my;`, just bear in mind that there will be no variable named `NAME.my`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set explicit fields... for example:

```
let x = (function(){
    let obj = {}; // the "namespace"
    let private_var = 0;
    function foo() {
        return private_var++; // Access private vars freely
    };
    obj.foo = foo; // "publish" the function
    console.log(foo()); // you can use unqualified foo here
    return obj;
})();

// outputs 0 from the console log call inside the "constructor"

console.log(x.private_var); // undefined, it's not published
console.log(x.foo()); // outputs 1, the function was published
console.log(x.foo()); // 2
console.log(x.foo()); // 3
```

Local variables or local functions of a Javascript function are not implicitly published anywhere. If you want to access them then you need to set up an object field.

Comment: Thanks but this example code doesn't solve my problem. As mentioned by @Alnitak and @GerardoFurtado, the problem is that an IIFE is executed immediately, the variable `NAME.countryDoubleClicked` instead is set only when the user double-clicks on a country.

Comment: @KatherineMaurus: Unless you set up somewhere `<whatever>.my = something` the code `console.log(<whatever>.my)` will always say `undefined` (or crash if `<whatever>` ends up being `null` or `undefined`). In the code shown `my` is just a local variable of a local scope and not a field of any object, no way it can show anything as apparently you think it should. No matter how many times you double-click things around.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the **Original Module pattern** above the Revealing Module pattern, mainly because of the benefits of loose augmentation; In short, it allows to break up a module into parts which can be loaded asynchronously, read more [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).

Via `window.NAME = window.NAME || {}` in the code below a custom namespace with name NAME gets declared if it doesn't exist yet. Module 1 declares a variable `my` into it and module 2 a variable `other`; whether module 1 runs before or after module 2 doesn't matter.

When the main module gets executed (after module 1 and 2) it can access the variables defined in both. Notice that these can be accessed in 3 different ways.

```js
// Module1.js.
(function(NAME) {

    NAME.my = "foo" // Replace with your map instance.
    
})(window.NAME = window.NAME || {});


// Module2.js.
(function(namespace) {

    namespace.other = "bar"
    
})(window.NAME = window.NAME || {});


// Main module using what is defined in the 2 modules above.
(function(namespace) {

    console.log(NAME.my);
    console.log(namespace.my)
    console.log(window.NAME.my);
        
    console.log(NAME.other);
    console.log(namespace.other)
    console.log(window.NAME.other)
    
})(window.NAME = window.NAME || {});
```